# delete an empty line before matched pattern

Tags: python

I am trying to write a new line before matching `'find me'` but my code writes an empty line to the output file. How can I get rid of that empty line (line after 41.4 gram)?

```
    with open("input.txt", "r") as infile:
        readcontent = infile.readlines()

    with open("output.txt", "w") as out_file:
        for line in readcontent:
            if line.strip() == 'find me':
                out_file.write('Added New line')
            out_file.write(line)
```

input.txt:

```
[atom]
molecules 
41.4 gram

find me
2.1 kcal
completed
```

obtained output.txt:

```
[atom]
molecules 
41.4 gram

Added New line
find me
2.1 kcal
completed
```

Desired output.txt:

```
[atom]
molecules 
41.4 gram
Added New line
find me
2.1 kcal
completed
```

Comment: Is there always a blank line before "find me", and is a blank line always followed by "find me"? Do you want to get rid of all empty lines, or just those before "find me" (and replace those with different text)?

Comment: There is only one a blank line before "find me".  I want to get rid of only that blank line.

Comment: If that's the only blank line, don't go looking for "find me" and then try to get rid of the blank line before that: Instead, just look for the blank line itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, you want to skip outputting a blank line if the next line is `find me`. Since you already have all the lines in `readcontent`, you can simply peek ahead with the next index:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as infile:
    readcontent = infile.readlines()

with open("output.txt", "w") as out_file:
    for index, line in enumerate(readcontent):
        if not line.strip() and readcontent[index + 1].strip() == 'find me':
            continue
        if line.strip() == 'find me':
            out_file.write('Added New line\n')
        out_file.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are just chasing a blank line. we throw in .isspace as a check and you never write any lines that are blank or only contain whitespace characters.

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as infile:
    readcontent = infile.readlines()

with open("output.txt", "w") as out_file:
    for line in readcontent:
        if line.strip() == 'find me':
            out_file.write('Added New line')
        if not line.isspace:
            out_file.write(line)
```

Edit: Changed based on commenter below

Comment: You have to call the function, also `line` will never be `None`: `if not line.isspace():`; or `if line.strip():`

Comment: Should be noted that this will discard *all* lines that are empty or contain only whitespace, which may not be desirable.

Comment: I felt that was clear when i wrote "never write any lines that are blank or whitespace" ?